# Placing labels on data points in a stacked bar chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, timeline, data-visualization

Is it possible to place the labels not on the Y axis, but on the data point itself in a stacked bar chart in excel?

I am trying to modify the timeline template available [here](http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/timeline.html) so that my labels for each bar appear over or next to the bar rather than all the way on the left side.

See the image below for how it looks now.

[image: timeline]

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/194041/excel-scatter-chart-with-labels/194756#194756 points to a similar issue, but for XY plots in specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In playing with Excel, it looks like you can right-click on the dataset and select "Add Data Label." I'm not sure how to replicate what you have exactly.
[image: Like so]

Comment: wow. Thanks Chris. /me goes and hangs head in the corner for not seeing the right-click option!

Comment: I'd still like to be able to put the *names* on the bars, in addition to the data labels, but this is a good start :)

Comment: Once you've added the data labels, you can edit them manually. I'm playing with Excel now, if I can figure how to do it automatically, I'll let you know.

Comment: this *is* very close to what I'm looking for, and is a great start towards my final goal :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [XY Chart Labeler](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm).  It's an excel add-in and contrary to it's name, it supports many chart types.

Don't thank me, User [Toc](https://superuser.com/users/11028/toc) posted [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/194041/excel-scatter-chart-with-labels/194756#194756) in the question you referenced.

Comment: I saw "XY Chart Labeler" from that other question ... even referenced it in the comment I left on the question :) ..however, it *seems* to only support scatter plots (from what I read about it)

Comment: It will do bars & columns, but Chris's answer is still better!